# SharePoint people picker. Show other AD attribute

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, active-directory, people-picker

Is any way to show other field from AD in `PeoplePicker` control ?

E.g. from `extensionAttiribute1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. 
"User" field (People picker) can display different data, such as "Office". Data is retrieved from **SharePoint User Information List**. This is hidden list. We can add fields to this list in "Site settings"->"Users and groups"->"List settings". Next we must write code to add data from **Active Directory** to our new field in user information list.
But if we have non foundation edition of SharePoint (Standart or Enterprise) - we can use **SharePoint User Profile Service Application** (further **SPUPS**) for our purposes. We can add new field in user profile, map this field to **Active Directory** attribute, mark field as "replicable" and start full syncronization. After that we can see our new field was added from user profile in **SharePoint User Information List** by **SPUPS**. That's all.